# How to create XDocument from XML file embedded resource

Tags: .net, xml, embedded-resource, linq-to-xml

My class library has a folder called 'Foo' containing an XML file called 'Bar.xml' whose Build Action is set to Embedded Resource.

I would like to create an XDocument from this file.

How hard can it be?

(Answer: hard enough to stump me for the last half an hour.)

Comment: Is there any particular reason it has to be an embedded resource?

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried so far?! This is normally the way i do it

```
var manager = new ResourceManager("name.to.my.resource.set", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

using (var s = manager.GetStream("myDoc"))
{
   return XElement.Load(s);
}
```

Comment: I feel your pain. I hate it when people do that.

Comment: what is **name.to.my.resource.set**? I am used to find resources by appending the project relative filename to the assembly's default namespace and convert any slashes to dots.